# how to set up 2 virtualhosts with the same root adress?

Tags: wordpress, apache2, virtualhost

I'd like to set up 2 wordpress sites on the same ip adress, that is `ip_adress1/wordpress1` and `ip_adress1/wordpress2`.

I put these 2 files into /etc/apache2/sites-available (these are basically the same, only site's path changes)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress/MyFirstSite/
ServerName my.ip.adr.ess
ServerAlias my.ip.adr.ess/MyFirstSite/*
ServerAdmin myemail@adress.ext

Alias /MyFirstSite /usr/share/wordpress/FolderForMyFirstSite
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/FolderForMyFirstSite>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/FolderForMyFirstSite/wp-content>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress/MySecondSite/
ServerName my.ip.adr.ess
ServerAlias my.ip.adr.ess/MySecondSite/*
ServerAdmin myemail@adress.ext

Alias /MyFirstSite /usr/share/wordpress/FolderForMySecondSite
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/FolderForMySecondSite>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/FolderForMySecondSite/wp-content>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems that the 2 sites in sites-available can work separatly when I enable them.

When I enable both of them simultaneously though, only one works. I think it's overwriting the other... (no apache error, by the way)

One other thing : the sites works when I reach `http://my.ip.adr.ess` (without the path for the site). And that I'dont't want it to !

What do you think ?

Many thanks in advance

Stanislas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this,finally, which seems better, after reading a bit more docs (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) about apache configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress
ServerName my.ip.adr.ess
ServerAdmin my.email@adress.ext

Alias /Alias1 /usr/share/wordpress/Folder1
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/Folder1>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/Folder1/wp-content>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /Alias2 /usr/share/wordpress/Folder2
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/Folder2>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress/Folder2/wp-content>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```